# Finding all primes $k$ such that some integer right triangle with perimeter $510$ has area $510k$

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangles, area

So I've tried this question for a while now, but can't seem to get an answer. I tried to equate $z$ but don't know how to proceed. Can someone help?

> In a $\triangle XYZ$, $\angle XYZ = 90^\circ$. Also $XY= x$, $YZ = y$, and $ZX = z$.
>
> Suppose that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers, perimeter $P= 510$, and area $A= kP$, for some prime number $k$. Determine all possible values of $k$.

---

My solution so far

---

[image: My solution so far]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you for your comment, I have edited the question

Comment: "If 2 completly divides, it means the numeratior is a multiple of $2$ then $K$ can not be prime"  I don't follow.  That means the *numerator* isn't prime but $K$ and the numerator are not the samething.  If $255 -z = 2p$ then $K = \frac {2p} p = p$ and that of course *can* be prime.  If $255-z = 14$ or $26$ or $62$ or anything that is $2$ times  prime then $K = \frac {14}2$ or $\frac {26}2$ or $\frac {62}2$ or $\frac 2p$ and those are $7, 13, 31$ or any $p$ and those *ARE* prime.

Comment: Actually, since I was able to pare the candidate values for $k$ down to a manageable size, I've decided to try to *complete* the problem by determining which candidate values do each permit at least one integer pythagorean triple.  If I succeed, then I will drop you another comment.

Comment: Solution completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added an Addendum which completes the solution.

---

Just added analysis to the end of this answer, which improves the lower bound on $z$ from $(z > 170)$ to $(z > 211).$

---

This is a **partial solution** (only).

You are given that:

- $x,y,z \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $x^2 + y^2 = z^2.$
- $x + y + z = 510.$
- $(1/2) \times (xy) = 510k \implies (xy) = 1020k ~:~k~$ prime.

Then
$\displaystyle
(510 - z)^2 = (x+ y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = z^2 + 2040k \implies$

$\displaystyle
(510)^2 + z^2 - 2(510)z = z^2 + 4(510)k \implies$

$\displaystyle
(510)^2 - 2(510)z = 4(510)k \implies$

$$(510) - 2z = 4k \implies 255 - z = 2k.\tag1$$

This is the same formula that the OP reached.

---

The upper bound of $\displaystyle k \leq 127$ may be routinely improved.

Since $x^2 + y^2 = z^2,$ you know that $x < z$ and $y < z$.

Therefore $\displaystyle 3z > (x + y + z) = 510  \implies z > 170.$

Using equation (1) above, since  $z\displaystyle \geq 171, ~~2k \leq (255 - 171) = 84 \implies k \leq 42.$

Therefore, the only **candidate** values for $k$ are 
$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41\}.$

Personally, I see no alternative to brute force examination of each of the candidate values to determine which ones are viable.

---

**Edit**
Analysis may be used to determine a larger minimum value for $z$, which in turn would determine a smaller maximum value for $k$.

Suppose $y = rx, r > 0.$

Then $~~\displaystyle x^2 + r^2x^2 = z^2 \implies 
x^2 (1 + r^2) = z^2 \implies $ 
$\displaystyle x = z\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}} \implies y = z\frac{r}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}}.$

Then, $~~\displaystyle 510 = (x + y + z)
= z\left[\frac{1 + r}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}} + 1\right].$

Therefore, the minimum value for $z$ is determined by determining which value for $(r)$ maximizes 
$\displaystyle \frac{1 + r}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}}.$

which is equivalent to determining which value for $(r)$ maximizes 
$\displaystyle \frac{(1 + r)^2}{1 + r^2} = 
\frac{1 + r^2 + 2r}{1 + r^2} = 1 + 2\frac{r}{1 + r^2}.$

The question has therefore been simplified to determining which value for $(r)$ maximizes 
$\displaystyle \frac{r}{1 + r^2}.$

Let $~~\displaystyle f(r) = \frac{r}{1 + r^2}.$

Then, $\displaystyle f(1) = (1/2)$.

Suppose that $\displaystyle r = 1-s,$ where $0 < s < 1.$

Then $\displaystyle f(r) = \frac{1 - s}{1 + (1-s)^2}
= \frac{1 - s}{1 + 1 - 2s + s^2}
< \frac{1 - s}{2 - 2s} = \frac{1}{2}.$

Similarly, suppose that $\displaystyle r = 1+s,$ where $0 < s.$

Then $\displaystyle f(r) = \frac{1 + s}{1 + (1+s)^2}
= \frac{1 + s}{1 + 1 + 2s + s^2}
< \frac{1 + s}{2 + 2s} = \frac{1}{2}.$

Therefore $\displaystyle f(r) = \frac{r}{1 + r^2}$ obtains a maximum value at $r = 1$.

This implies that the minimum value for $z$ is obtained when $x = y$.

$\displaystyle x = y \implies 2x^2 = x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \implies 
x = y = z\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \implies $

$\displaystyle 510 = x + y + z = z\left(1 + \sqrt{2}~\right).$

Therefore, the minimum value for $z$ is
$\displaystyle \frac{510}{1 + \sqrt{2}} > 211 \implies 
(2k) < (255 - 211) = 44 \implies k < 22.$

Therefore, the set of candidate values for $k$ has been reduced to 
$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}.$

---

---

---

**Addendum**
Completing the solution.

Using the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), the generating function for primitive pythagorean triples is

$$x = m^2 - n^2, ~y = 2mn, ~z = m^2 + n^2 $$

**[Constraint-1]:**
$\displaystyle \text{where} ~m,n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~~m > n, 
~~m,n ~~\text{relatively prime},$ 
$\displaystyle \text{and} ~~m,n ~\text{have different odd/even parity}.$

This implies that all pythagorean triples will have form
$$x = t(m^2 - n^2), ~y = 2tmn, ~z = t(m^2 + n^2) 
~~:~~ t \in \Bbb{Z^+} \tag2$$

subject to the Constraint-1 restrictions above.

Therefore,

- $\displaystyle (510) ~=~ x + y + z ~=~ 
  t[(m^2 - n^2) + 2mn + (m^2 + n^2)]$ 
  $\displaystyle  ~= 2t(m^2 + mn) ~=~ 2t(m)(m+n).$
- $\displaystyle (2^2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 17 \times k) = 1020k = (xy) = 2t^2(m^2 - n^2)(mn).$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~~x,y,z 
~~\text{is a primitive pythagorean triplet}}$
This implies that $t = 1$, which implies that 
$\displaystyle (3 \times 5 \times 17) = 255 = (m)(m+n),$ 
subject to the Constraint-1 restrictions above.

This leads to the following table:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  m & m+n & n \\
  \hline                       
  1 & 255 & 254 \\
  3 & 85 & 82 \\
  5 & 51 & 46 \\
  17 & 15 & -2 \\
  15 & 17 & 2 \\
  51 & 5 & -46 \\
  85 & 3 & -82 \\
  255 & 1 & -254 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

Therefore, under the assumption that $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet, the only entry in the above table that satisfies Constraint-1 on $m,n$ is $m = 15, n=2$.

This implies that $\displaystyle x,y = 221, 60~$ respectively, which
implies that 
$\displaystyle (xy) = (60 \times 221) = (1020) \times 13$ 
and that 
$\displaystyle z = \sqrt{(221)^2 + (60)^2} = 229 \implies 
(x + y + z) = 221 + 60 + 229 = 510.$

Therefore, if $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet, the only viable value for $k$ is $(k=13)$ which does generate an acceptable pythagorean triplet.

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~~x,y,z 
~~\text{is not a primitive pythagorean triplet}}$
This implies that $t > 1$, and 
$\displaystyle 1020k = (xy) = 2t^2(mn)(m^2 - n^2)$ 
which implies that $\displaystyle 510k = t^2(mn)(m^2 - n^2)$ 
which implies that
$\displaystyle 510k = (2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 17 \times k)$ **is not square free**.

With $(13)$ already verified as a feasible value for prime $k$ 
the remaining candidate values for $k$ are 
$\displaystyle \{2,3,5,7,11,17,19\}.$

This is an opportune moment to split these remaining candidate values of $k$ into two sets:

$$S_1 = \{2,3,5,17\} ~~\text{and}~~ 
S_2 = \{7,11,19\}.$$

Under the assumption that 
$\displaystyle (2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 17 \times k) ~~$ is not square free, 
the 3 elements in $S_2$ can be immediately rejected. 
Therefore, the elements in $S_1$ are the only elements
that remain to be considered.

This leads to the following table:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  (k = t) & (k^2 = t^2) & 510k 
& \left\{[mn(m^2 - n^2)] = \dfrac{510k}{k^2}\right\} 
& \left\{[m(m+n)] = \dfrac{510}{2k}\right\}\\
  \hline                       
  2 & 4 & 1020 & 255 & 127.5 \\
  3 & 9 & 1530 & 170 & 85 \\
  5 & 25 & 2550 & 102 & 51 \\
  17 & 289 & 8670 & 30 & 15 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

In the above table, $[k=2 \implies m(m+n) = 127.5]$ is immediately rejected.  For the remaining entries, brute force can be avoided by noticing that

$$(mn)(m^2 - n^2) = (m)(m+n)(n)(m-n) \implies $$
$$\frac{(mn)(m^2 - n^2)}{(m)(m+n)} = (n)(m-n).$$

In the above table, in each of the entries, you have that 
$\displaystyle (n)(m-n) = \frac{(mn)(m^2 - n^2)}{(m)(m+n)} = 2.$ 
This implies that both $(n)$ and $(m-n)$ are factors of $(2)$. 
This implies that $(m,n)$ must be $\in \{(3,1), (3,2)\}.$

This leads to the following table:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  (k = t) & (m,n) & x & y & z & (x + y + z) & (xy) \\
  \hline                       
  3 & (3,1) & 24 & 18 & 30 & 72 & 432 = 144k \\
  3 & (3,2) & 15 & 36 & 39 & 90 & 540 = 180k \\
  5 & (3,1) & 40 & 30 & 50 & 120 & 1200 = 240k \\
  5 & (3,2) & 25 & 60 & 65 & 150 & 1500 = 300k \\
  17 & (3,1) & 136 & 102 & 170 & 408 & 13872 = 816k \\
  17 & (3,2) & 85 & 204 & 221 & 510 & 17340 = 1020k \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

Therefore, in Case 2, only $k =  17$ satisfies all of the constraints.

---

Therefore, the only allowable values for $k$ are $(k=13)$ and $(k=17)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is not exactly right. Suppose $z = 251$. Then $$k = \frac{255-251}{2} = \frac{4}{2} = 2$$ which is prime.

One solution just by looking at the Pythagorean triples might be to just figure out if any of them work with a perimeter of 510. For example, $(5, 12, 13)$ is a well-known primitive triple. Also,
$$ 5a + 12a + 13a = 510 \implies a = 17 $$

Thus, $$x = 5a = 85 \\ y = 12a = 204 \\ z = 13a = 221$$ is an integer set of sides which satisfies your solution since $$k = \frac{255-221}{2} = \frac{34}{2} = 17 $$ which is prime.